# Where do I place custom git commands when using msysgit?

Tags: git, msysgit

I want to create my own custom command for git but don't know where to put the file once I have created it. It will be a simple shell script file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put it in some directory where the environment variable `PATH` points to (check with `echo $PATH`).